# Julia how to eval the sym

Tags: julia

Help! I got a result in the form of sym. But it seems eval doesn't work. How can I get a numerical answer? Thanks.

```
@show BBias

@show eval(BBias)

@show typeof(eval(BBias))



BBias = -213.53387843501*cos(6) + 73.4119295548356*sin(6) - 50*sin(6)*cos(6) + 316.255048160247

eval(BBias) = -213.53387843501*cos(6) + 73.4119295548356*sin(6) - 50*sin(6)*cos(6) + 316.255048160247

typeof(eval(BBias)) = SymPy.Sym
```

Comment: In Python, you'd do something like `float(BBias)`. [The README of the Julia wrapper](https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl/blob/master/README.md) seems to contain some Julia examples that do something similar (in particular, the lines ending with `|> float`). Does that help?

Comment: Which symbols or results are you getting? Here, when I execute the expression (`BBias = ...`), it gives me `104.12805497344107` (without any symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a symbolic SymPy expression, not a Julia expression. `eval` in Julia will only evaluate a Julia expression. The `N` function from SymPy will evaluate and expression down to it's floating point value.

You can do a `typeof(BBias)` to see what kind of an object this is. Since I don't know how you have generated that object, I cannot replicate it fully. But here is some simple example showing how to using SymPy from Julia

```
julia> using SymPy

julia> x=Sym("pi")
pi

julia> typeof(x)
SymPy.Sym

julia> y=sin(x)
0

julia> typeof(y)
SymPy.Sym

julia> typeof(eval(y))
SymPy.Sym

julia> z=N(y)
0

julia> typeof(z)
Int64
```

A detailed tutorial on using SymPy from Julia is available here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jverzani/SymPy.jl/blob/master/examples/tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Thanks! N(BBias) solves the problem. The type is SymPy.Sym :)